# In modulation between minor and Major, is V7 considered minor or Major?

Tags: chords, modulation

In the little piece below, E7 can either by five chord of Major or harmonic minor. Is it identified as Major chord or harmonic minor chord? Or maybe it does not really matter?

[image]

Comment: It's definitely a major chord because it has a major third. There is actually nothing like a "harmonic minor chord". Chords a either major or minor (not considering dim, aug)  and this is determined by its third. In this piece its function is clearly a dominant regardless if you see the key as A minor or A major. The author of the piece considered the key as mainly A minor because he set the key signature to A minor (no accidentals).

Answer (score 0):

Whichever way you go with changing to parallel keys, V will be more effective than v.

The ^3 of V is the leading note, one semitone below the root of the parallel key chord. It just sounds so much more convincing. In a minor key, even then, it's far more common to see V rather than v, for the same reason. Assuming I read the question correctly!

Answer (score 0):

The `V` chord is just identified as a `V` chord. The key is designated separately.

For example, "The piece is in A minor, and here is the `V` chord."

or

"This is a `V` chord leading to a major (or minor) chord."

Answer (score 0):

E7 is a major chord.  Period.   It's used as V7 in both A major and A minor.

Don't get hung up on the idea that the natural minor is somehow the 'authentic' minor scale.   Melodic minor and Harmonic minor are equally valid.